# How to open URL on new window using java on production server

Tags: java, linux

I need to open URL on new window using java , I am able to open url on new window but on my production I am not able to open.

I am following the below link

https://www.mkyong.com/java/open-browser-in-java-windows-or-linux/

How to open url on new window?

Comment: You pasted a link to code that does exactly what you want. What more do you need?

Comment: I need to open url like(https://www.google.co.in/) using java class.

Comment: On my local machine I am able to open url on new tab but when I am deploying my project on web server. didn't work

Comment: What does it do? Does it throw any exceptions or anything?

Comment: No exception found

Comment: That's because the code you shared catches _all Exceptions_ and swallows them... What OS is your production server running? Does it have any of the listed browsers installed?

Comment: On production linux OS and I don't know about browsers installation

Comment: If there's no browser, it isn't going to be able to open the webpage. So the chances are you don't have the browser installed.

Comment: Can you please share me command for check installed browser on linux system.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the link you gave is opening a web page in a browser program that is running on the same machine as the java program. This will work when the program runs on a desktop machine like a Windows box or a linux desktop machine. Therefore it works without problems on your local machine.

But what machine is the web server you deployed to? Probably some linux server running without a display attached in a provider's computer center. This web server likely will have no browser installed which you could use to open the URL, and even if so on what screen?

`RunTime.exec()` returns a `Process` object, did you check if the output returned from the process object and/or it's exit value?

**Edit:** As Brandon said, the code you show swallows and ignores exceptions that might be thrown, so you actually don not see if anythings goes wrong.

Comment: You should mention how the code swallows `Exception`. This means that if anything goes wrong then nothing is printed out.